# double value rounding causes division error

Tags: c++, double

```
double s = 30e-9; // this is in fact 29.9999997e-9
double ns = s * 1e9; // this is equal to 29.9999997
double ref_ns = 5;

cout << fmod(ns, ref_ns); // rest of 29.9999997 mod 5, is indeed 4.999997
```

the value printed is 5 (4.999997 rounded)
I would expect to have 0 as result.
How can I deal with this issue ?

Comment: Why did you expect 0?

Comment: 30 mod 5 should give 0

Comment: How you deal with this depends on what you want to do with the result. If you want accuracy don't use floating point

Comment: Watch this : [Floating point numbers, Computerphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZRI1IfStY0) presented by Tom Scott

Comment: @tony_merguez -- [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

Comment: You don’t have 30 mod 5. You have 29.9999997 mod 5.

Comment: *this is in fact 29.9999997e-9*  This is, in fact, `0.00000002999999999999999731895437469174348077416425439878366887569427490234375`

Comment: @AlanBirtles what should I use then ?

Comment: Fixed point, if it's appropriate to your application